# Open a new window tab but with URL showing that of localhost

Tags: jquery, html, window, title

I have the following code which opens a window in a new tab :

```
function openMapTab(lat, lng) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/DisplayMap",
    dataType: "text",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var w = window.open();
        $(w.document.body).html(data);
    },
  });
}
```

So this opens Google map in a new window tab but in the browser URL, I have this:

> about:blank

I would like it to display something like:

> http://localhost/Maps

in the url.

I tried adding a title to the window as below:

```
var w = window.open("Maps");
```

But this does not work.

Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible for security reasons. Imagine if it was; I could create a page which looks like your bank then change the URL to match theirs and phish your login.

Comment: Yeah you are right